# Replace domain transparently to the user

Tags: apache

I have a domain www.domainA.com where I run my internet store. 
I would like to open another domain www.domainB.com that would actually be served by www.domainA.com behind the scene.

So that when the user would be entering www.domainB.com, he would stay on www.domainB.com, but  behind the scene all requests would go to www.domainA.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a virtual host for domainB that points to the webroot op of domainA. Nothing special about it. Beware of getting a penalty for duplicate content though; search engines don't like it if you host the same content on different domains.